# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' > (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting

Tags: php

> I have this error message "**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>'
>   (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'**" , as I want to create 2D of array to pass the 2 keys into foreach loop .

```
$productIds = array
  (
  [0] => Array
        (
            [SKU] => 'xx'
            [Price] => 22

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SKU] => 'bb',
            [Price] => 15,

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [SKU] => 'cc',
            [Price] => 5,

        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [SKU] => 'tt',
            [Price] => 17,

        )
```

Comment: Post the code with which you are creating the array

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a comma in your array when you create that array, it should be:

```
 Array
    (
        [SKU] => 'xx',
        [Price] => 22

    )
```

Instead of

```
 Array
    (
        [SKU] => 'xx'
        [Price] => 22

    )
```